# Question on Transit visa in Saudi Arabia

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, saudi-arabia

Hi I Am traveling from Rome to Dammam and Dammam to Hyderabad india I have 7 hrs of layover do I need a transit visa ? I have to self transfer

Comment: It may not be relevant but what nationality are you?

Comment: And what is your status in Italy? Do you have a visa or a resident permit?